# C++17 ECS Implementation

Tags: c++, c++17, entity-component-system

I am (relatively) new to game programming and have been exploring creating an entity component system for my simple 2D game engine.

Here is what I have so far:

**Entity.h**

```cpp
#pragma once

using Entity = int;
```

**ComponentArray.h**

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "Entity.h"
#include <unordered_map>

class ComponentArrayAbstract {};

template<typename T>
class ComponentArray : public ComponentArrayAbstract {
public:
    void                            AddComponent(Entity entity, T component);
    void                            RemoveComponent(Entity enitity);

    T&                              GetComponent(Entity entity);

private:
    std::unordered_map<Entity, T>   mComponents;
};

template<typename T>
void ComponentArray<T>::AddComponent(Entity entity, T component) {
    mComponents.emplace(entity, component);
}

template<typename T>
void ComponentArray<T>::RemoveComponent(Entity entity) {
    mComponents.erase(entity);
}

template<typename T>
T& ComponentArray<T>::GetComponent(Entity enitity) {
    return mComponents[enitity];
}
```

**ECSManager.h**

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "Entity.h"
#include "ComponentArray.h"
#include <bitset>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

const int MAX_COMPONENT_TYPES = 32;

using ComponentType      = int;
using ComponentSignature = std::bitset<MAX_COMPONENT_TYPES>;

class ECSManager;
using System             = std::function<void(ECSManager*, double)>;

class ECSManager {
public:
                              ECSManager() = default;
                              ~ECSManager();

                              ECSManager(const ECSManager& other)            = delete;
                              ECSManager(ECSManager&& other)                 = delete;
                              ECSManager& operator=(const ECSManager& other) = delete;
                              ECSManager& operator=(ECSManager&& other)      = delete;

    // Entity Functions
    Entity                    CreateEntity(int id); // TODO: use hashed string ids instead.
    void                      DestroyEntity(Entity entity);
    template<typename... Args>
    std::vector<Entity>       GetEntitiesWith();
    template<typename T>
    T&                        GetComponent(Entity entity) const;

    // Component Functions
    template<typename T>
    void                      RegisterComponentType();
    template<typename T>
    void                      AddComponent(Entity entity, T component);
    template<typename T>
    void                      RemoveComponent(Entity entity);

    // System Functions
    void                      AddSystem(System system);
    void                      UpdateSystems(double deltaTime);

private:
    ComponentSignature        GetComponentSignature(Entity entity) const;
    void                      SetComponentSignature(Entity entity, ComponentSignature signature);
    template<typename T>
    ComponentArray<T>*        GetComponentArray() const;
    template<typename T>
    ComponentType             GetComponentType()  const;
    int*                      GetComponentCount() const;
    template<typename T>
    ComponentSignature        CreateComponentSignature() const;
    template<typename T, typename Second, typename... Args>
    ComponentSignature        CreateComponentSignature() const;

    std::unordered_map<Entity, ComponentSignature>           mComponentSignatures;
    std::array<ComponentArrayAbstract*, MAX_COMPONENT_TYPES> mComponentArrays;
    std::vector<System>                                      mSystems;
};

template<typename... Args>
std::vector<Entity> ECSManager::GetEntitiesWith() {
    ComponentSignature systemSignature = CreateComponentSignature<Args...>();
    std::vector<Entity> entities;
    for (auto i : mComponentSignatures) {
        if ((i.second & systemSignature) == i.second) entities.push_back(i.first);
    }
    return entities;
}

template<typename T>
T& ECSManager::GetComponent(Entity entity) const {
    return GetComponentArray<T>()->GetComponent(entity);
}

template<typename T>
void ECSManager::RegisterComponentType() {
    mComponentArrays[GetComponentType<T>()] = new ComponentArray<T>();
}

template<typename T>
void ECSManager::AddComponent(Entity entity, T component) {
    GetComponentArray<T>()->AddComponent(entity, component);
    SetComponentSignature(entity, GetComponentSignature(entity).set(GetComponentType<T>(), true));

}

template<typename T>
void ECSManager::RemoveComponent(Entity entity) {
    GetComponentArray<T>()->RemoveComponent(entity);
    SetComponentSignature(entity, GetComponentSignature(entity).set(GetComponentType<T>(), false));
}

template<typename T>
ComponentArray<T>* ECSManager::GetComponentArray() const {
    return ((ComponentArray<T>*) (mComponentArrays[GetComponentType<T>()]));
}

template<typename T>
ComponentType ECSManager::GetComponentType() const {
    static int index = (*GetComponentCount())++;  return index;
}

template<typename T>
ComponentSignature ECSManager::CreateComponentSignature() const {
    ComponentSignature signature;
    signature.set(GetComponentType<T>(), true);
    return signature;
}

template<typename T, typename Second, typename... Args>
ComponentSignature ECSManager::CreateComponentSignature() const {
    ComponentSignature signature;
    signature.set(GetComponentType<T>(), true);
    signature |= CreateComponentSignature<Second, Args...>();
    return signature;
}
```

**ECSManager.cpp**

```cpp
#include "ECSManager.h"

#include "ComponentArray.h"
#include <unordered_map>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

ECSManager::~ECSManager() {
    for (ComponentArrayAbstract* componentArray : mComponentArrays) {
        if (componentArray != nullptr) {
            delete componentArray;
        }
    }
}

Entity ECSManager::CreateEntity(int id) {
    mComponentSignatures.emplace(id, ComponentSignature());
    return id;
}

void ECSManager::DestroyEntity(Entity entity) {
    mComponentSignatures.erase(entity);
}

ComponentSignature ECSManager::GetComponentSignature(Entity entity) const {
    return mComponentSignatures.at(entity);
}

void ECSManager::SetComponentSignature(Entity entity, ComponentSignature signature) {
    mComponentSignatures[entity] = signature;
}

void ECSManager::AddSystem(System system) {
    mSystems.push_back(system);
}

void ECSManager::UpdateSystems(double deltaTime) {
    for (System system : mSystems) {
        system(this, deltaTime);
    }
}

int* ECSManager::GetComponentCount() const {
    static int componentCount = 0;
    return &componentCount;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include "ECSManager.h"
#include <stdio.h>

struct Component1 {
    int num1;
};

struct Component2 {
    int num2;
};

void TestSystem(ECSManager* world, double deltaTime) {
    for (Entity entity : world->GetEntitiesWith< Component1, Component2>()) {
        Component1 component1 = world->GetComponent<Component1>(entity);
        Component2 component2 = world->GetComponent<Component2>(entity);

        printf("%i\n", component1.num1 + component2.num2);
    }
}


int main() {
    ECSManager world;
    world.RegisterComponentType<Component1>();
    world.RegisterComponentType<Component2>();

    Entity entity1 = world.CreateEntity(1);
    world.AddComponent<Component1>(entity1, {1}); // I will use hashed string ids in the future.
    world.AddComponent<Component2>(entity1, {2});

    Entity entity2 = world.CreateEntity(2);
    world.AddComponent<Component1>(entity2, {3});
    world.AddComponent<Component2>(entity2, {4});

    world.AddSystem(TestSystem);

    world.UpdateSystems(0.16);

    return 0;
}
```

I have a few questions:

- Implementation:

  Is the implementation flawed in any way, eg. are my uses of std containers appropriate? Is it relatively cache friendly? (I'm looking at the unordered map of entities). I initially wanted to make `ECSManager` a namespace with functions, like my other subsystems (`Renderer`, `Input`, etc. I don't know if this is a good idea either!). Is this feasible, or a good way to do it? I decided not to, since there are lots of template functions, so accessing data would be a pain.
- Style:

  Are there any issues with the way I have written my code? Should I implement the `ECSManager` functions in a cpp file, since most are template functions anyway?
- API:

  Is the API realistic and scalable? Is it holding me back in any way?
- Have I made any silly mistakes?

Comment: `ComponentArray` is basically useless as it is just a worse `std::unordered_map`. Also introducing type-erared classes for templates without reason  makes no sense either (Im talking about `ComponentArrayAbstract.

Comment: if you want to have a "default" container for your code base, e.g to be able to quickly switch implementations consider using `using` instead. Also any container class should be able to accept arbitrary allocators (have a look at how std containers are designed)

Comment: Oh and you might want to check out boost hana for heterogenous containers (containers which can store objects of more than one type). Especially `hana::map` which can be used to map types to arbitrary objects

Comment: Your ECSManager manager needs to implement the rule of five. As it is now horrible things will happen if you copy an instance of it and move semantics are disabled.